# HVAC air flow question

Tags: hvac

What is an appropriate distance between a finished floor and bottom of an interior door to make sure there is adequate HVAC air flow when door is closed.
Several sites say in order for there to be proper air flow the doors would need to be at least 1 1/4" off the floor (*doesn't look right*) and that the HVAC unit will not last as long if there is restricted air flow. The alternative is to put air returns in every room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years ago, every room had a cold air return. Today, most HVAC systems have a central return air grill. In order to get air delivery into that room, the bottom of the doors need to be trimmed. I am from the "old school" and still believe in a return grill in every room except the bath room and the kitchen. Why the central return grill, installed cost, of course. Now we see questions as to "how can I reduce the noise coming into a bedroom"? Easy, insulate the walls, add a return in that room, and replace the door which has had the bottom cut off to enhance air flow.  My 2 cents.